# Python Importing files from other folders (within the same project) using __init__.py?

Tags: python, import, directory

Trying to import aFile.py from within the bSubFile.py but getting an error saying 'exceptions.ValueError, Attempted relative import in non-package'

My file structure is as follows:

```
app/
  - __init__.py

  FolderA/
    - __init__.py
    - aFile.py

  FolderB/
    - __init__.py
    - bFile.py

    SubfolderB/
      - __init__.py
      - bSubFile.py
```

I am trying to import aFile from bSubFile.py

tried:

```
from ..FolderA import aFile

class bSubFile():
...
```

and:

```
from ...FolderA import aFile

class bSubFile():
...
```

but I always get 'Attempted relative import in non-package', I must be missing something very obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: Try `from app.FolderA import aFile`

Comment: from app.folderA import aFile just gives me an error of 'No module named app.FolderA' @drum

Comment: Add it to FolderA/__init__.py as well

Comment: Forgot to ask, is aFile the method or class? Or just filename?

Comment: aFile is just the filename

Comment: When you do `import A, B, C`, these are the constants, functions and classes. You don't import the file name

Answer (score 0):

You can add the other path to your system path. This may be not the most elegant way, but it works.

```
import sys
import os
# get the folder of the current file, go one directory back and add "FolderA"
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "FolderA"))
# now you can import everything that is in FolderA directly
import aFile
```